# mod_jk for Apache/2.4.6 on RHEL release 7.2

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, mod-jk

**How to load the module mod_jk ?**

I am getting the following error :

> Cannot load modules/mod_jk.so into server:
>   /etc/httpd/modules/mod_jk.so: undefined symbol: ap_get_server_version

Which is possibly because of the version mismatch.

Comment: that module was compiled for a different version of Apache probably. So to load it grab the right version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install mod_jk.so, the module had to be compiled first. You can download the latest version and compile it.

I followed the following link and it worked for me :

http://www.diegoacuna.me/installing-mod_jk-on-apache-httpd-in-centos-6-x7-x/

Comment: Link broken: https://web.archive.org/web/20191002005058/http://www.diegoacuna.me/installing-mod_jk-on-apache-httpd-in-centos-6-x7-x/